# Flutter: Create a flutter project with Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, flutter

Flutter allows supporting of Kotlin language.

[image]

How can I integrate my Kotlin file with Flutter project?

There is no option to add/create a Kotlin file (in `New` menu) in Android Studio.

[image]

Comment: Where are you trying to add your kotlin/swift file ?

Comment: I created a new Flutter project with Kotlin support enabled. Now I guess, it should allow me to create a Kotlin file and use Kotlin as base language along with Dart. So I'm trying create Kotlin file (similar to main.dart). Is that possible.

Comment: Yeah but where are you trying to put these files ? As they are used only inside /android and /ios folders

Comment: Did you check https://flutter.io/developing-packages/ Instead of Java you can use Kotlin. See also the existing plugins as examples https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages (they don't use Kotlin though)

Comment: Can't I place/put it with main.dart (lib) ?

Comment: No, you can't just mix Dart an Kotlin. Kotlin has to go inside the android project blow the android directory

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer So, I guess by default it use Java code file for android but if i enable kotlin, then it use kotlin... Do you mean the same?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think the kotlin files can only be used in the platform-specific plugins. E.g. you have platform-specific implementation for both iOS and android and you can use kotlin for the Android part.
The Flutter SDK is used directly with `Dart`.

Answer (score 5):

[image: Follow this]

Open your Android module in android so you can add your kotlin files

Comment: the next part I want to find out is how to trigger code within the Android subproject

Answer (score 1):

Flutter does not support Kotlin and it looks it will not allow Flutter to be written in Kotlin language. The biggest advantage of using Dart language is the management of the object. It has a great garbage collector. Don't you think google developers didn't think about that before? Of course, they did. But Dart is chosen as the one language of Flutter.